# Using toolchain with proper vendor name

Tags: gcc, makefile, toolchain

I must use an external toolchain in order to compile some source code I'm given. The source code doesn't come with a Configure file, only with a, what seems to be, automatically generated Makefile.

The Makefile makes references to `mips-linux-[cc|ar|ld|...]`, but the toolchain I'm provided has a different naming.

Is there any way I can tell `make` to use another naming scheme?

Comment: `make` does nothing more than follow whatever's written in the makefile, it might be a case of overriding a variable like `make target=some-other-linux`, but if you don't post at least an excerpt it's impossible to say.

Comment: There should be a variable defined in Makefile with `CC=mips-linux-` you can override this by passing argument to make command like `make CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is: CROSS=my-custom-toolchain-prefix